# Projectiles (coefficient of restitution)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I know that horizontal velocity of a projectile remains constant, and that horizontally, there is zero acceleration.

So if I am given the following problem:

A ball of mass $150$ g is thrown at $15.0$ m s$^{-1}$ in a direction that is $15.0^{\circ}$ above the horizon from a height of $1.50$ m above the ground. Assuming that acceleration due to gravity g = $10.0$ m s$^{–2}$, and with a detailed explanation of your method, determine the time taken from when the ball leaves the thrower’s hand to it landing on the ground.

Can I do this?

Horizontally, speed remains constant:

$v_{0} = 15.0\cos(15.0^{\circ})$ m s$^{-1}$

$v = 15.0\cos(15.0^{\circ})$ m s$^{-1}$

$a = 0$ m s$^{-2}$

$t = $ ?

But then if I were to use the SUVAT equation $v = v_{0} + a t$, the velocities would cancel out, and the time would be zero anyway since acceleration is zero.

I know that I can find it using vertical components, but if this were the only information I had, would there be any way to find the time?

Comment: It's pretty unusual to see intro-level problems with uncertain values, e.g. $g=10.0\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^2}$.  Do they mean to imply that you should do an uncertainty analysis, or are they just writing like that as a quirk?

Comment: @Nat What do you mean by uncertain values?

Comment: The $.0$ stuff, e.g. as in $10.0\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^2}$ rather than just $10\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^2}$.  The notation is used to imply precision limits, which in turn imply that the true value is unknown and that you just have an approximate range, e.g. $10.0\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^2}$ basically means $\in\left(10{\pm}0.05\right)\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^2}$.

Comment: @Nat Significant figures or decimal places are insignificant in this case (no pun intended).

Comment: Well, you have a bit of a problem in your argument. For the case of the horizontal velocity, the SUVAT equation you mention is just an identity. And look! Since the accelaration is $0$, the time can be anything! Thus just shows that this equation is not helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Your method will work if you apply it to the *vertical component of motion*.

First, take the initial vertical component of the velocity ( $vsin\theta$ ) and notice that the velocity component is the same at the end of the trajectory, just with the reversed sign( $-vsin\theta$ ). Put these (former as initial and latter as final velocity) in the equation you mention and you will get the time when the ball again returns to the height you threw it from.

The next part is just normal one dimensional motion ( a ball dropped with a certain velocity ). Find this time and add both of them.

Voila! You have found out the total time of flight!

Comment: Your answer ignores the fact that the end of the trajectory is below the starting point...

Comment: @DJohnM My bad. I did not read the question properly. Thanks for the heads up